# Populate and show datatable on selection

Tags: primefaces

I want to populate and display datatable after user select a user from a selectmenu as below:

```
<div align="center">
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{dtEditView.user}" >
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="FastWeb" itemValue="FastWeb"/>
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="george" itemValue="george"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu><p:spacer/>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dtEditView.enabletable()}" update="data"/>
<p:outputPanel id="data">
                    <p:dataTable id="users1" var="user" value="#{dtEditView.users1}" editable="true"  resizableColumns="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" widgetVar="usersTable" rendered="#{dtEditView.showtable}">
<p:column headerText="No" filterBy="#{user.no}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{user.no}">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{user.no}" /></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{user.no}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="A/C No" filterBy="#{user.USERID}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{user.USERID}">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{user.USERID}" /></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput2" value="#{user.USERID}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column> 
</
</p:dataTable>
                    </p:outputPanel>
```

My managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="dtEditView")
@ViewScoped
public class EditView implements Serializable {
private List<User> users1;
@ManagedProperty("#{quantumService}")
    private QuantumService service;
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
           users1 = service.createUsers(user);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EditView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


 public List<User> getUsers1() {
        return users1;
    }
```

The class is too big so am just giving part of the code to demonstrate what I have done so far. I am passing item selected to the method which queries users from database and creates a list which I in turn use to populate my datatable.

Comment: Hi, if the class is too big, it is not a [mcve]. Please learn how to create one. It helps you narrow down the problem and them makes it easier for us to help solve your remaining problem if you did not already found the cause by making a [mcve]. And it is not clear what your actual problem is...

Comment: Thanks, am still new here... am learning , I will check on this

Comment: My objective is to populate a datatable after user select item on SelectOneMenu. I use the value selected to filter result from database so that user will view data for only selected item.